# Get random elements from array and show how many times occurs in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have long string which I split after each 4th char. After that I want to take 3 random of them and show how many times are in the array.

What I have is

```
$string = "AAAAAAABAAACAAADAAAEAAAFAAAGAAAHAAAIAAAJAAAKAAALAAAMAAANAAAOAAAPAAAQAAARAAASAAATAAAUAAAVAAAWAAAXAAAYAAAZAAAaAAAbAAAcAAAdAAAeAAAfAAAgAAAhAAAiAAAjAAAkAAAlAAAmAAAnAAAoAAApAAAqAAArAAAsAAAtAAAuAAAvAAAwAAAxAAAyAAAzAABAAABBAABCAABDAABEAABFAABGAABHAABIAABJAABKAABLAABMAABNAA";
$segmentLength = 3;
$totalLength = strlen($string);
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalLength; $i += $segmentLength) {
    $result[] = substr($string, min($totalLength - $segmentLength, $i), $segmentLength);
}

print_r(array_rand(array_count_values($result), 4));
```

`array_count_values($result)` output is

```
Array
(
    [AAA] => 19
    [ABA] => 1
    [AAC] => 1
    ........
    [AAL] => 1
    [MAA] => 1
    [AAB] => 4
)
```

I'm trying with `print_r(array_rand(array_count_values($result), 4));` to output

```
Array
    (
        [AAA] => 19
        [ABA] => 1
        [AAC] => 1
        [AAB] => 4
    )
```

or

```
Array
    (
        [ABA] => 1
        [AAC] => 1
        [AAL] => 1
        [MAA] => 1
    )
```

instead I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => AHA
    [1] => AAa
    [2] => zAA
    [3] => BGA
)
...
Array
(
    [0] => GAA
    [1] => AxA
    [2] => CAA
    [3] => BGA
)
... so on
```

Comment: The string is really big one and the overlapping will be very low chance to happen but generally is okay.

Comment: I actually got your question now.

Comment: Look at using `$result = str_split($string, $segmentLength);` to split the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the result of `array_count_values($result);` to a variable and then get a random set of keys from that result. Then loop through that random list of keys and generate your desired output. For example:

```php
$string = "AAAAAAABAAACAAADAAAEAAAFAAAGAAAHAAAIAAAJAAAKAAALAAAMAAANAAAOAAAPAAAQAAARAAASAAATAAAUAAAVAAAWAAAXAAAYAAAZAAAaAAAbAAAcAAAdAAAeAAAfAAAgAAAhAAAiAAAjAAAkAAAlAAAmAAAnAAAoAAApAAAqAAArAAAsAAAtAAAuAAAvAAAwAAAxAAAyAAAzAABAAABBAABCAABDAABEAABFAABGAABHAABIAABJAABKAABLAABMAABNAA";
$segmentLength = 3;
$totalLength = strlen($string);
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalLength; $i += $segmentLength) {
    $result[] = substr($string, min($totalLength - $segmentLength, $i), $segmentLength);
}

$countedValues = array_count_values($result);

$randValues = array_rand($countedValues, 4);

$output = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($randValues); $i++) {
    $key = $randValues[$i];
    $output[$key] = $countedValues[$key];
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: Do I need another loop in order to echo in more readable way `$output` instead of `print_r`.

Comment: You could just output in the for loop that builds `$output`, but generally speaking most likely you need to loop through it in some way.